# Unknown command 'nand' - try 'help' on beaglebone black

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot

I'm trying build a linux system on `beaglebone` black and following to mastering embedded linux programming book, however when I boot my `u-boot` on beaglebone black, I have received a error: `unknown command 'nand' - try 'help'`.

Does anybody have any idea of what did I do wrong or did I miss something?

Comment: Probably expects something ancient. BBB doesn't have NAND and I'm not even sure if U-Boot is set up to write anything to eMMC or SD unless you are using an ancient image with a FAT partition.

Comment: Really?? I'm following  mastering embedded linux programming book. They are guiding me as follows cmd  : nand read 82000000 400000 200000 . And this book were reprinted by Chris Simmonds in 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in **Chapter 3: All About Bootloaders** *→ U-Boot → Using U-Boot*:

- This is *NOT* an example meant to be executed on a BeagleBoneBlack.
- It is a *generic* example of a U-Boot command that possibly could work on hardware that actually has NAND flash. The BBB does not have raw NAND flash, it has an eMMC and a micro-SD card slot.

If that's not where you are in the book, please provide chapter information and what you are trying to achieve.

BTW: please also note that there are [errata for this book](https://www.packtpub.com//books/content/support/20382), especially around U-Boot and the NAND commands. You might want to verify if they apply to your reprint.

Comment: Hi TBR ! . I understood it . Thanks you very much

Comment: Hi TBR ! sorry I researched again and I realized the beaglebone black had eMMC (nand flash)

Comment: eMMC is **managed** NAND. There is no direct way to access the NAND in an eMMC, you talk to the controller, which does all the necessary management like load levelling. The U-Boot NAND commands pertain to *raw NAND flash*.

Comment: Hi TBR. According to  this link can using  nand on u-boot https://e2e.ti.com/support/arm/sitara_arm/f/791/p/344528/1206203

Comment: Quoting from that very page and it's accepted answer: `Regarding the eMMC, the "nand" commands won't work with it. There are a set of "mmc" commands in U-Boot,`. If you want to play with NAND flash, you will need a device with NAND flash. The BBB is **NOT** such a device, though you *could* buy a NAND module and somehow attach it. I consider this matter fully settled and will not reply further.

Comment: Hi TBR , May be i understood it.  So How can I flashing my linux system on sdcard to beaglebone eMMC?

Comment: That was not your question. If that is your question you **must** open a new question and explain properly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The command *nand* is only available in U-Boot if CONFIG_CMD_NAND=y is configured.

Use *make menuconfig* for configuration.

Comment: I'm searching CONFIG_CMD_NAND on u-boot menuconfig , but I don't see that

Comment: Are you using mainline U-Boot? To display the search field type a slash '/'.

Comment: Hi Xypron. Where is it? I can not find

Comment: Hi Xypron. Thanks you. I found it , it is "Command line interface > Device access commands > nand".