# Flash linux system on beaglebone black

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

Sorry my english is not good.

I'm following this tutorial (https://embedjournal.com/kernel-compilation-beaglebone-black/) , and I built a linux system, I  had 2 partitions(BOOT,RFS) and i booted it on the beaglebone black by sdcard . At the moment, i don't know to flash the linux system on beaglebone black. when I bought the beaglebone black , it had a debian distro maybe the debian distro ran on the NAND flash ,  so i think my linux system can boot by NAND flash on the beaglebone .

Does anybody have any idea of what did I do wrong or did I miss something?

Comment: You can try to install debian using an external pen drive.

Comment: Hi Joaozito Polo ! I don't think it supports for me because i want to boot my linux system by NAND Flash on board :(

Comment: It's only to install the first time... after installed, it will boot directly by NAND Flash. I have a similar situation here, and I needed to use this approach.

Comment: Hi Joaozito Polo. Sorry ,I don't understand, my beaglebone black had debian distro and now I want to change debian to my linux system

Comment: Hm, now I understood. I thought it was a laptop, but now I looked for it. You need to flash the internal card like this article http://derekmolloy.ie/write-a-new-image-to-the-beaglebone-black/

Comment: Hi Joaozito Polo. I don't have solution for it. how to am i convert 2 files RFS and BOOT to file.img

Comment: Hi Joaozito Polo. will you give me a url for this solution??

Comment: Sorry, I only had that link (derekmolloy.ie)

Comment: Hi Joaozito Polo, no problem , thanks you for everything :D

Answer (score 0):

As you are [following the Book "Mastering Embedded Programming"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702875/unknown-command-nand-try-help-on-beaglebone-black/51723068?noredirect=1#comment90514706_51723068), I'd like to direct you towards Chapter 5. It describes various steps in this domain, also using the BBB.

If you find that book hard to follow, you could consider following [this page that is entirely devoted to getting a Linux system onto a BBB](https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black) from `A` to `Z` and even provides `#exactsteps` for most.

Personally I'd recommend to use a SD-card for your experiments, while completely deleting all eMMC content, including U-Boot.

SD-card and eMMC for all intents and purposes on the BBB behave exactly the same and it's a lot easier to take out the SD-card and examine its contents on a Linux computer.

Comment: Hi TBR , I ran a custom linux on bbb used SD-card. After that, I held boot button before powered on bbb, But nothing was happen

Comment: Hi TBR , I build root file system according to the book. In chap 5 building a root file system , I don't missing anything and don't have any bugs . But I can't run it and I had a error " unable to mount rootfs  " . I searched a lot of but I don't have any solution  . will you explain it to me?

Comment: your question does not say anything about "unable to mount rootfs". Please edit your question and provide details.

Comment: hi TBR I created a new question for that in this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819139/umount-mmcblk1p1-on-beaglebone-black