# Error while unmounting mmcblk1p1 on beaglebone black - during repartitioning and formatting

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

Hi I'm a newbie of embeded linux. I'm following this tutorial (https://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/linux/f/354/t/398780?Script-to-Erase-Emmc-independently-Beagle-Bone-Black)  for flashing my linux system to beaglebone eMMC.
But I have an error: `umount: can't umount /dev/mmcblk1p1: Invalid argument`

This is my cmd :

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 3825 MB, 3825205248 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 116736 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 64 * 512 = 32768 bytes

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/mmcblk1p1   *        2048        2536       15648   e Win95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk1p2               1        2047       65496  83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table
[  235.274729]  mmcblk1: p1 p2

root@beaglebone:/# umount /dev/mmcblk1p1

umount: can't umount /dev/mmcblk1p1: Invalid argument
```

Sorry my English is not good. Does anybody have any idea of what did I do wrong or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

This is an error in the script you are following. If you have created new partitions without a file system you would not expect them to be mounted.

Creating the 2nd partition in sectors 1 - 2047 is probably not what you want to do. You should use all the space after partition 1.